# calling Outlook asnychronously from c#

Tags: c#

I have created a class in C# in .Net 5 with a single function to perform the following:

1. find emails that are unread in a specific folder.
2. save the email in text format to a folder in disk.
3. set the flag on the email message and save the email.

This class works fine.  I now want to make this an async method, so that it doesn't freeze my wpf view.  That is where I'm having a problem.  I have posted the class code below that isn't working.

Any help is  appreciated.

'''

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ASR.WPF.Outlook
{
    public class EmailApp
    {
        public Task<int> FetchMail()
        {
            Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
                                            .Folders["_ArcServe"]
                                            .Folders.GetFirst();

            int _processCount = 0;
            string _folderName = @"c:\work\arcserve\process\";

            try
            {
                foreach (MailItem msg in oFolder.Items)
                {

                    if (msg.UnRead == true)
                    {
                        string detail = msg.Body;
                        string fileTag = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", msg.ReceivedTime);
                        string fileName = _folderName + "digest_" + fileTag + ".txt";

                        // delete existing file if it exists
                        if (File.Exists(fileName))
                        {
                            File.Delete(fileName);
                        }

                        // write the new file
                        File.WriteAllText(fileName, detail);

                        //msg.UnRead = false;
                        msg.Save();

                        _processCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                oFolder = null;
                oNS = null;
                oApp = null;
            }

            return _processCount;

        }

    }
}
```

'''

Comment: You should read about [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) in C#, then run the tasks on a GUI separated thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is not decorated with `async`, so the compiler wants you to return `Task<int>` instead of `int`. Your signature should be `public async Task<int> FetchMail()`. After changing it you should find in the method all the places where you could await some method. It basically means you should find methods that have `Asnyc` overloads. You could, for example, use `FileStream` which has such overloads instead of static `File` which has not.

E.g.

```
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(detail);
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, buffer.Length, true))
{
     await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

However, if it turns out that there is no `Async` overload for the method that causes most of that freeze, then I suggest you keep this method sync, I mean without `Task` and `async` and call it from the WPF using `Task.Run` or `BackgroundWorker`.